# Can the "Max number of persistent disks" limit be raised?

Tags: google-compute-engine

In the Persistent Disk Size Limits documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#pdlimits) it says:

> Standard, high memory, and high CPU machine types can attach up to 16 persistent disks.

Is this a limit that can be raised?

We would like to run many docker containers per machine and give each of them a persistent disk (so they aren't tied specifically to that machine). The current limit would only let us run 16 containers per VM, which is a much lower number than we'd like.

On [AWS HVM instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html), we can attach up to 73 EBS volumes.

Thanks.

Comment: According to the link https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#pdlimits that you provided, the maximum is 16 and cannot be increased. Try to do partitions on the disks and assign these partitions to the dockers.

Comment: NB: that link also states that "instances with shared-core machine types or custom machine types with less than 3.75 GB of memory are limited to a maximum of **4 persistent disks**"...

Answer (score 2):

No, it presently cannot. I have just been advised that the number of PDs attached to an instance is fixed.

Comment: Links can be helpful as supplemental information, but [link-only answers are strongly discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/228805). Please include a summary of the linked information that's relevant to the question, and explain how it resolves the issue. Also, please leave the signature out of your posts. That's what your profile is for. Answers should be about answering the question, not about the person who's answering the question.

Comment: My apologies. I should have stopped after the first sentence, "Yes, the limit can be raised."

Comment: In that case the answer would probably have been deleted. If you don't explain how, it's really not an answer. A comment at best.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Amazon's documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/volume_limits.html#linux-specific-volume-limits), it is inadvisable to attach more than 40 disks per instance.